# Can I add a new branch protection rule via GitHub API?

Tags: github-api

I know you can update an existing branch protection rule via the API, but I cannot find any references in the v3 API docs WRT creating a new rule. For example, if I want to add a rule to a repo that matches a new branch prefixed with "dev_", I have to add it through the GUI, using the "Apply rule to" field, then I can use the API to update those rule settings. Ideally, I'd like to have a hook that does this automatically if a new branch is introduced to the repo, but does not match an existing rule. I should be able to create that rule through the API. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you find out how to accomplish this? I'm looking for the same, but according to the documentation, it is still possible to add restrictions only by using full branch name and not a  pattern... (what is possible via web interface)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's still not possible, AFAIK anyhow, to use wildcards with any of the API endpoints. So you either have to enforce a policy whereby users are only allowed to create branches with predetermined prefixes/suffixes that match existing branch protection regex's. Or, you would have to repeatedly run an API script (or whatever) to update the protection rules every time a new branch was added.

Answer (score 7):

FYI for those finding this now - there is an API so you don't have to use GraphQL if you don't want.

https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/rest/branches/branch-protection#update-branch-protection

```bash
curl \
  -X PUT \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/branches/BRANCH/protection \
  -d '{"required_status_checks":{"strict":true,"contexts":["continuous-integration/travis-ci"]},"enforce_admins":true,"required_pull_request_reviews":{"dismissal_restrictions":{"users":["octocat"],"teams":["justice-league"]},"dismiss_stale_reviews":true,"require_code_owner_reviews":true,"required_approving_review_count":2,"bypass_pull_request_allowances":{"users":["octocat"],"teams":["justice-league"]}},"restrictions":{"users":["octocat"],"teams":["justice-league"],"apps":["super-ci"]},"required_linear_history":true,"allow_force_pushes":true,"allow_deletions":true,"block_creations":true,"required_conversation_resolution":true}'
```

Edit: Even though the API says this is for `update`, it does create new branch protection rules as well.

Comment: This API is only for updating the details of an existing branch protection rule. This doesn't answer the original question of how to *create* a branch protection rule.

Comment: @lukekarrys I guess that's what they titled it (`update`), but I can confirm that this does create NEW branch protection rules as well.

Comment: Sad - I 
> The name of the branch. Cannot contain wildcard characters. To use wildcard characters in branch names, use the GraphQL API.

Answer (score 6):

It appears that GitHub has decided to add new features via the GraphQL API only, not via the REST API. So while this is impossible with the REST API, you can do it using the GraphQL [`createBranchProtectionRule` mutation](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations#createbranchprotectionrule).

In case it helps anyone, I wrote a script to do this, using [GitHub's `gh` CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -ue
err() { echo 1>&2 "$*"; }
die() { err "ERROR: $*"; exit 1; }
mustBool() {
        [[ "${1#*=}" = "true" || "${1#*=}" = "false" ]] ||
                die "bad boolean property value: $1"
}
mustInt() {
        [[ "${1#*=}" =~ [0-9]+ ]] ||
                die "bad integer property value: $1"
}

[ $# -ge 4 ] || {
        err "usage: $0 HOSTNAME ORG REPO PATTERN [PROPERTIES...]"
        err "   where PROPERTIES can be:"
        err "           dismissesStaleReviews=true|false"
        err "           requiresApprovingReviewCount=INTEGER"
        err "           requiresApprovingReviews=true|false"
        err "           requiresCodeOwnerReviews=true|false"
        err "           restrictPushes=true|false"
        exit 1
}
hostname="$1"
org="$2"
repo="$3"
pattern="$4"
shift 4

repoNodeId="$(gh api --hostname "$hostname" "repos/$org/$repo" --jq .node_id)"
[[ -n "$repoNodeId" ]] || die "could not determine repo nodeId"

graphql="
mutation createBranchProtectionRule {
        createBranchProtectionRule(input: {
                repositoryId: \"$repoNodeId\"
                pattern: \"$pattern\""

seen=()
requiredStatusCheckContexts=()
for property in "$@"; do
        for eSeen in "${seen[@]:-}"; do
                [[ "${eSeen%%=*}" = "${property%%=*}" ]] &&
                # Allow duplication of multivalued properties
                [[ "${eSeen%%=*}" != "requiredStatusCheckContexts" ]] &&
                die "Duplicate property: $property"
        done
        seen+=("${property}")

        case "$property" in
        requiredStatusCheckContexts=*)
                requiredStatusCheckContexts+=("${property#*=}")
                ;;
        \
                allowsDeletions=* | \
                allowsForcePushes=* | \
                dismissesStaleReviews=* | \
                isAdminEnforced=* | \
                requiresApprovingReviews=* | \
                requiresCodeOwnerReviews=* | \
                requiresCommitSignatures=* | \
                requiresLinearHistory=* | \
                requiresStatusChecks=* | \
                requiresStrictStatusChecks=* | \
                restrictPushes=* | \
                restrictsPushes=* | \
                restrictsReviewDismissals=* \
        )
                mustBool "$property"
                graphql="$graphql
                ${property%%=*}: ${property#*=}"
                ;;
        requiredApprovingReviewCount=*)
                mustInt "$property"
                graphql="$graphql
                ${property%%=*}: ${property#*=}"
                ;;
        *)
                die "unknown property: $property"
        esac
done

if [ -n "${requiredStatusCheckContexts[*]:-}" ]; then
        graphql="$graphql
                requiredStatusCheckContexts: [
"
        i=0
        for context in "${requiredStatusCheckContexts[@]}"; do
                [ $i -ne 0 ] && graphql="$graphql,
"
                i=$((1+$i))
                graphql="$graphql"$'\t\t\t'"\"$context\""
        done
        graphql="$graphql
                ]
"
fi

graphql="$graphql
        }) {
                branchProtectionRule {
                        allowsDeletions
                        allowsForcePushes
                        creator { login }
                        databaseId
                        dismissesStaleReviews
                        isAdminEnforced
                        pattern
                        repository { nameWithOwner }
                        requiredApprovingReviewCount
                        requiresApprovingReviews
                        requiredStatusCheckContexts
                        requiresCodeOwnerReviews
                        requiresCommitSignatures
                        requiresLinearHistory
                        requiresStatusChecks
                        requiresStrictStatusChecks
                        restrictsPushes
                        restrictsReviewDismissals
                }
                clientMutationId
        }
}"

gh api --hostname "$hostname" graphql -F "query=$graphql" ||
        die "GraphQL update failed: $graphql"
echo ""
echo "SUCCESS: Branch protection rule successfully created"
```

Here is an example of invoking it it:

```
./createBranchProtectionRule.sh github.example.com skissane my-repo v* requiresApprovingReviews=true requiresCodeOwnerReviews=true requiredApprovingReviewCount=1 requiresStatusChecks=true requiresStrictStatusChecks=false requiredStatusCheckContexts=continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge requiresLinearHistory=true
```

which produces the following output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "createBranchProtectionRule": {
      "branchProtectionRule": {
        "allowsDeletions": false,
        "allowsForcePushes": false,
        "creator": {
          "login": "skissane"
        },
        "databaseId": 1729,
        "dismissesStaleReviews": false,
        "isAdminEnforced": false,
        "pattern": "v*",
        "repository": {
          "nameWithOwner": "skissane/my-repo"
        }
        "requiredApprovingReviewCount": 1,
        "requiresApprovingReviews": true,
        "requiredStatusCheckContexts": [
          "continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge"
        ],
        "requiresCodeOwnerReviews": true,
        "requiresCommitSignatures": false,
        "requiresLinearHistory": true,
        "requiresStatusChecks": true,
        "requiresStrictStatusChecks": false,
        "restrictsPushes": false,
        "restrictsReviewDismissals": false
      },
      "clientMutationId": null
    }
  }
}

SUCCESS: Branch protection rule successfully created
```

Comment: I have to say that I `+1` the answer for mention of the missing REST API and the query API to use but the bash code is kinda messy and while I consider myself somewhat fluent in bash this could be easier to understand had you used 1. Associative Arrays and 2. Functions.  Other things that might help readability is either here-docs or use of `jq` to format / validate

Comment: @nhed I didn't use associative arrays because at my work we use macOS as a development platform and macOS bash is only bash 3. Yes people can install a newer bash (using Homebrew or whatever) or use zsh instead (as Apple recommends), but in practice I just stick to writing scripts in bash 3. Also not sure what you mean by "had you used... functions" since I am using functions, unless you mean use them more.

Comment: that's a bummer on the bash 3 front,and yeah I meant in building up the json.  I just mean the "main" body is kinda hard to digest, that's all

Answer (score 2):

This did it for me for GitHub Enterprise.

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://github.company.com/api/v3/repos/ORG/REPO-NAME/branches/BRANCH-NAME/protection' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
--header 'Accept: application/vnd.github.luke-cage-preview+json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic .................... \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '{
    "required_status_checks": {
        "strict": false,
        "contexts": ["continuous-integration/jenkins/BRANCH-NAME"]
    },
    "enforce_admins": true,
    "required_pull_request_reviews": {
        "dismissal_restrictions": {},
        "dismiss_stale_reviews": true,
        "require_code_owner_reviews": true,
        "required_approving_review_count": 1
    },
    "restrictions": {
        "users": ["users"],
        "teams": ["teams"],
        "apps": ["apps"]
    }
}
'
```

Comment: That's not what the question is asking. The question is asking how to create via API a branch protection rule *based on a name pattern*, not just one for a single named branch.

Comment: yeah the REST API sure seems to have a huge hole here.  The WEB UI is already in terms of a pattern.  but clearly the rest API as documented only seems to use the url mentioned in this answer which is for a specific branch.